# Is there a way to list the enumerations created with 'use enum'?

Tags: perl, enums

The documentation for the CPAN module 'enum' lists an example:

```
use enum qw(
    BITMASK:BITS_ FOO BAR CAT DOG
    ENUM: FALSE TRUE
    ENUM: NO YES
    BITMASK: ONE TWO FOUR EIGHT SIX_TEEN
);
```

> In this case, BITS_FOO, BITS_BAR, BITS_CAT, and BITS_DOG equal 1, 2, 4
> and 8 respectively. FALSE and TRUE equal 0 and 1. NO and YES also
> equal 0 and 1. And ONE, TWO, FOUR, EIGHT, and SIX_TEEN equal, you
> guessed it, 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16.

My question:

Is there a way to dump this constuction?  Either before or after it's inserted into the symbol table?

That is, I want to dump what was created, in its entirety, to verify it, or use it to create documentation.  Or maybe export them.

If it's constructed the way I think it may be, I can see why this might be challenging.

Comment: Quick look at source: No.

Comment: You're fast.  Should I just try to harvest the parser from the code?  I just need the names of the "enums" and then I can just query them.

Comment: What I mean is `my @myEnums = qw(...); parse();use enum @myEnum;`

Comment: I ended up adding the feature, myself.  It was 5 lines, which I sent to the maintainer for consideration.  I added a hash to the module which adds the name of the constant when it's created.